# Android DB SQLite Cursor Performance

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, cursor

Using _cursor.moveToNext() to iterate through the cursor, which is taking 4-5 seconds (the sql query itself takes milliseconds).

(Would like to avoid using cursorLoader as a workaround as I have the need to retrieve all data at once, prior to any rendering logic)

Is there any way to speed up iterating through the cursor?

Sample code:

```
Cursor _cursor = _db.rawQuery([optimized query, only takes a few ms], null);

// query returns about 1000 records, cursor loop is where the bottleneck seems to be

            while(_cursor.moveToNext()) {
                DtoObject obj           = new DTOObject();
                stop.name        = _cursor.getString(0);
                stop.last_name         = _cursor.getString(1);
    }
```

Comment: Use Traceview to determine **exactly** what is "taking 4-5 seconds".

Comment: What is inside your loop? `moveToNext` by itself should by fast as lightning.

Comment: That's likely because your query (whatever it is) is too complex.